# Setting default CHARSET and DB Engine

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, mariadb, character-set

I recently updated my server's database system from MySQL to MariaDB.
After update, everything works well.

But, when I went to phpMyAdmin, the default charset and types are changed:

[image: MySQL chareset and type info]

At the end of this image, the default type was set to 'InnoDB' and charset was set to 'latin1_swedish_ci'.
They were 'MyISAM' and 'utf8_general_ci' before.
How can I revert my character set and type settings back, and how can I customize settings when I make new database?

When I looked at /etc/my.cnf and /etc/my.cnf.rpmnew, I couldn't find any settings related to DB type/charset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"How can I revert my character set" :*

```
ALTER TABLE myTable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET "utf8";
```

*"How can I revert my type": (MySQL Engine):*

```
ALTER TABLE myTbale ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

*"how can I customize settings when I make new database?"*

**In your my.cnf**

```
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
```

Best Regards.

Max.

Answer (score 0):

- You can change server's **charset** and **collation** by editing `my.cnf` file and restart MySQL server to have effect

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-server.html

- Now all your tables are of Engine type as **InnoDB**, if you are using MariaDB 5.6+ then it can support Fulltext search with InnoDB which is primary reason before v5.6 to use MyISAM table. Now, you can get rid of MyISAM tables
  You can have a look at this blog post
  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/07/31/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-3/ (You can refer part-1 and part-2) as well for better understaning why we should use InnoDB rather than MyISAM in v5.6
- You can specify **charset** and **collation** as you would like while creating a database, a session level setting always overrides global level settings.
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-database.html